# how to dynamically add page using ng-include with asp.net MVC using angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-include

Here i am trying to call partial view from controller using angular js.

here is my code

```
<div ng-repeat='t in tabs'>
<div ng-include='t.templateUrl'></div>
<div>
```

when i try to include like ng-include="'/home/menutemplate'" it will includes the content. How can i dynamically do this? . Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.templateUrl` should be valid scope variable and should hold a string(path for the template):

```
$scope.t.templateUrl = "/home/menutemplate"
```

And in your template:

```
<div ng-include="t.templateUrl"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's exactly like what you did like this example

```js
      angular.module("app", []);

        angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter) {
   
            $scope.templates = [
                {url: "/Application/Partials/home.html"},
                {url: "/Application/Partials/page2.html"}
            ]

        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div ng-repeat="temp in templates">
            <div ng-include="temp.url"></div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Application/Partials/home.html">
            <h1>home.html is here</h1>
        </script>
        
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Application/Partials/page2.html">
            page 2 is here
        </script>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```